# Binary search a sorted list of integers

Tags: python, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

This code is meant to do a binary search of a sorted list containing integers.

I'm doing this to improve my style and to improve my knowledge of fundamental algorithms/data structures for an upcoming coding interview.

```
def bin_search(a, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(a) - 1
    found = False

    while first <= last and not found:
        mid = (first + last) // 2
        if a[mid] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            if item < a[mid]:
                last = mid - 1
            else:
                first = mid + 1

    return found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks pretty good to me.  Personally, I would get rid of the `found` variable and just `return True` if `item` is found.

I would also use a more descriptive name for the list.  `a` just doesn't say list to me.  If you want to keep it short, use something like `l` or borrow Haskell's convention and use something like `as` or `xs`.

Finally, if you wanted, you could use an `if`/`elif`/`else` instead of the `if`/`else` with nested `if`/`else` inside.  But I can't think of any compelling reason to do so.

As an answer to an interview question, I think you'll want to do a better job of indicating coverage of the case where the list is empty.  Your code covers this case perfectly (`last` will be `-1` and `first` will be `0`, so `first <= last` is `False`), but it's not obvious.  So it probably wouldn't hurt to add an explicit check or add a comment with a brief explanation why that case is covered.  Then there's no doubt that you considered that case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. All your suggestions were very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

For an interview question I would change two more things:

1. Use tuple assignment, `first, last = 0, len(a) - 1`
2. Add a descriptive docstring to describe what the function does and what it's parameters are:

```
def bin_search(a, item):
    """
    Binary search for an item in a sorted list.

    Args:
        a:     A sorted list
        item:  The item to search for
    Returns:
        True or False
    Raises:
        IndexError if a is not indexable

    If a has length zero, always returns False.
    """
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you make some good points. During an interview how much of the docstring do you think I should write. Since I don't have much time it might be a bit difficult to write down everything you mentioned. Nonetheless, thanks again :)

Comment: @cycloidistic Well all of it is pretty essential if you want to use the method. In this case I would probably leave out the raises because it is only the corner case if `a` is not actually list-like. This could be made clearer by using a different name than `a` as suggested in one of the other answers.

Comment: Sure. I'll keep that in mind from now on.